# Generating Image From Cell Array Using Imagesc Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell array (3 x 4), called output, containing a 1024 x 1024 matrix in each cell. I want to plot the 4 matrices in ouput{1,:}. Furthermore, I have a structure, called dinfo, which correspondingly contains the names of each matrix (field with matrix names = "name"). I want each image to be titled with its name. Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
for i = 1:length(output{1,:}) 
    figure 
    imagesc(output{1,i});
    colormap('jet')
    colorbar;
    title(num2str(dinfo.name(i)))
end
```

I keep getting the error that "length has too many input arguments". If I change the code to avoid the length function-related error:

```
for i = 1:4 
    figure 
    imagesc(output{1,i});
    colormap('jet')
    colorbar;
    title(num2str(dinfo.name(i)))
end
```

I get the error, "Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 4 results".

Any thoughts on how I could resolve both of these errors?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output{1,:}` is a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html); it contains the 1024 matrices of the first row of `output`, so `length` has 1024 arguments. The best way to obtain the number of columns is using `size(...,2)`:

```
for i = 1:size(output,2)
    figure 
    imagesc(output{1,i});
    colormap('jet')
    colorbar;
end
```

As for the second error, there is something wrong with `dinfo.name`; probably, it is also a comma-separated list because `dinfo` is a structure array. Try using `dinfo(i).name` instead of `dinfo.name(i)`.

Comment: Fantastic! I really appreciate your concise and helpful response!